# ALTER TABLE FOREIGN KEY from java to mysql

Tags: java, mysql, foreign-keys, alter-table

Well, I want to make a modification in my database, so I need to use alter table but java seems to have problems making that.

This is the sentence

```
ALTER TABLE loans ADD FOREIGN KEY (id_reader) REFERENCES readers (id);
```

how do you execute it?

I was doing this:

```
rawStatement="ALTER TABLE loans ADD FOREIGN KEY (id_reader) REFERENCES readers (id);";
currentStatement = conn.createStatement();
currentStatement.execute(rawStatement);
```

is the last line correct?

As far I know, `execute` must run everything.

Comment: I'm really sorry about my mistake.
I was reading the sql from a file with scanner, and i never realized that scanner wasnt loading the entire file, it stoped at the ALTER TABLE lines, causing the error, now im reading the entire file and the ALTER are working perfectly...
I kept using execute and it worked fine.
Again, sorry.

Answer (score 4):

Use [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate%28java.lang.String%29):

```
executeUpdate()
```

instead of

```
execute()
```

Also if the constraint is already present it will throw an exception

Other things you should look out for:

- Does the user have the privileges to alter the table?

Answer (score 2):

Try with the below code:

```java
rawStatement="ALTER TABLE loans ADD FOREIGN KEY (id_reader) REFERENCES readers (id)"; 
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(rawStatement);
ps.executeUpdate();
```